# How to define pattern in preg_replace to remove spaces?

Tags: php, string, design-patterns, preg-replace

I have a string like this.

```
$string="howto old_iccid    = 01920930123 new_iccid =102930123"
```

How to remove space character in order to get string like this:

```
$string="howto old_iccid=01920930123 new_iccid=102930123"
```

I have used `preg_replace`, but still not understand to define the pattern which is handling those things..

How to define pattern in preg_replace to remove spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$string = "howto old_iccid    = 01920930123 new_iccid =102930123";
$string = preg_replace('/\s*=\s*/', '=', $string);
var_dump($string);
```

Comment: OK.. Thank's for helping.. it works good..

I have another case
how to remove space in character we need, for example
$string = "howto old_icci d    = 01920930123 new_i ccid =102930123";
in order to get the same result like the question that i've asked before..
OUTPUT $string="howto old_iccid=01920930123 new_iccid=102930123"
Thanks for helping

Comment: @user1562370 So what about `howto` ?

Comment: I ignore it, I want to process string on '$str' variable to get the value of 'old_iccid' and 'new_iccid' that lies on that string '$str'..
But now I already have the solution.. Thanks for helping..